# Voxelization of an .stl file in Pyhton

Tags: python, preprocessor, open3d

I am trying to do a DataScience project and therefore need to feed an .stl file into a deep model.
I am imagining that a voxelized version of the triangular mesh would work best. Conditions for this voxel representation are that the object in the .stl file has to be filled so that the deep model can comprehend the volume of the object in 3D space.
So far I am able to convert the file to a binary numpy array that contains voxels of the surface of the object and even the surface has many empty spots. In general I am very unsatisfied with the results. Below is the code, which I was able to come up with.

```
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np

mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh("../Sample_Model/backpack_hook.stl")

mesh.scale(1 / np.max(mesh.get_max_bound() - mesh.get_min_bound()),
           center=mesh.get_center())

voxel_grid = o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid.create_from_triangle_mesh(mesh, voxel_size=0.05)
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([voxel_grid])

voxels = voxel_grid.get_voxels()
indices = np.stack(list(vx.grid_index for vx in voxels))

a = np.zeros(shape=(np.amax(indices[:, 0]+1), np.amax(indices[:, 1]+1), np.amax(indices[:, 2]+1)))

for i in range(indices.shape[0]):
    coords = indices[i]
    a[coords[0], coords[1], coords[2]] = 1

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# change the last parameter to move through the z axis
plt.imshow(a[:, :, 3],interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

I have read in past posts that this is quite a difficult problem and so I am not looking into implementing this myself but am hoping that there is a script outthere already doing what I require.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach filling the shape using the even-odd rule. You cast a ray from a position into a direction and count the number of intersections. If the number is odd the voxel at this position must be filled. Repeat this using 3 for loops (x, y, z, increment is the resolution of your voxel system) and you have got a 3d voxel representation of your vertex collection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not think that that could easily work because the surface that I currently receive as an output in voxel form still has way too many holes to use ray tracing accuratly.

Comment: It is not a closed mesh?